# How to log Mocha/Chai HTTP requests

Tags: ecmascript-6, mocha.js, chai

Hi I am new to Mocha/Chai.

I am trying to test some HTTP requests. If would be nice if I could log the actual test request to debug it.

The code I am using looks something like

```
  describe('Get token for super user', () => {
     it('it should get a valid token set', (done) => {
          let req = chai.request(app)
             req
           .get('/oauth/token')
           .set('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
           .set('Authorization','Basic blah')
           .field('grant_type', 'password')
           .field('username', superUser)
           .field('password', superPass)
           .end((err, res) => {
               console.log('*******' , req)
               res.should.have.status(200)
               done()
           })

   })
  })
```

How would I log the request itself, I don't see a neat way of doing this from the API docs ?

Comment: What do you mean by **request itself** ?

Answer (score 1):

You can log `res.request`:

```
.end((err, res) => {
    console.log('*******' , res.request)
    // ...
  })
```

Or use the following function for easier debugging. The output looks like `curl -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"username":"647c9cf7af0cb7d7c9aac219", ...}' localhost:3000/oauth/token`

```
function logRequest(request) {
    console.log(`curl -X ${request.method.toUpperCase()} -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '${JSON.stringify(request._data)}' ${request.url}`);
}

// сall logRequest() like in the previous example 
.end((err, res) => {
    logRequest(res.request)
    // ...
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to get and log all info about request - response object:

```
chai.request('http://...')
    .post('/endpoint')
    .send('{"a":1}')
    .end((err, response) => {
        console.log(response);
        done();
    });
```